# Define primary and foreign keys in same object which use the sequence generators

Tags: java, jpa, sequence

I have created Address object which has a ID (AddressPK) which get generated by a sequence. The address object also has a foreign key to Client object via the ID of the client object (ClientPK). The ClientPK also generated via a sequence. However, it complains at the time I try to deploy the ear to web logic server saying that only one generated element can exist for an entity. The class snippets as follows. Anyone can help how to define a foreign key using an object that also uses a sequence generator in addition to the object primary key?

```
public class Address implements Serializable{
@EmbeddedId
private AddressPK id;

@Embedded
private ClientPK clientId;

...
}

@Embeddable
public class AddressPK implements Serializable {
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="RoidSequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="RoidSequenceGenerator",sequenceName="roid_sequence", allocationSize=1)    
@Column(name = "a_roid")
private long value;
...
}

@Embeddable
public class ClientPK implements Serializable {
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="RoidSequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="RoidSequenceGenerator",sequenceName="roid_sequence", allocationSize=1)
@Column(name = "c_roid")
private long value;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not understand what is the Primary Key and what the difference from the Foreign Key. Primary key (PK) can be generated for each database entity. And there is a restriction in JPA that generated value must be only one. Foreign Key (FK) in the other hand is a link to the PK of another entity. So you need to create another entity with generated PK and have a link to it with OneToMany, ManyToMany or another kind of association. For example:

```
@TableGenerator(name = "entities_id_generator", table = "SEQUENCE",                
pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue = 
"ENTITY_SEQ", initialValue = 0, allocationSize = 1)
public class DBObject1 implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "entities_id_generator", strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "source_id")
private DBObject2 source;
}

@TableGenerator(name = "entities_id_generator", table = "SEQUENCE",                 
pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue = 
"ENTITY_SEQ", initialValue = 0, allocationSize = 1)
public class DBObject2 implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "entities_id_generator", strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "source")
private List<DBObject1> objects;
}
```

In example above the virtual FK for entity `DBObject1` will be stored in column `source_id`. It is virtual because there will not be any physical FK in database table. But JPA will link these objects if you ask.

Comment: Does it matter it is a virtual FK or physical FK? Both has to be linked as you described above right? In this case, when we retrieve DBObject1 it will also load the DBObject2 using the FK?

Comment: You can create physical FK by hands. JPA or ORM will not do it for you. But physical FK can increase the performance of queries. Also the loading of linked entities controlled by `fetchType` attribute of association annotation. Take a look at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13765381/1051509).