# Spring Roo doesn't add FetchType.LAZY for fields in .aj files, Should I do it manually?

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, spring-roo

These are a couple of question, should Spring Roo through reverse engineering adding FetchType.LAZY for Set fields in .aj files or should I do it manually?

If FetchType.LAZY is not present at .aj files, I could make it through the queries " SELECT st1 FROM parentTable t1 JOIN FETCH t1.childTable st1" into the select, right ?

The point here is that I can add FetchType.LAZY to the files manually (Refactor .aj file > Push In..) and then on .java file (high risk if I want Roo to keep the control on my domain classes).

About to make it through queries, I can't do this because I'm getting:

```
> query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=ii,role=...domain.Industry.i18nIndustries,
tableName=..I18nIndustry,
tableAlias=i18nindust3_,
origin=..Industry industry2_,
columns={industry2_.IdIndustry ,className=..domain.I18nIndustry}}] 
[select u.idUserName, u.isActiveInd, u.employeeNbr, u.name, c.name as CompanyName, ii.name as IndustryName from Users u JOIN u.idCompany c JOIN c.idIndustry i JOIN FETCH i.i18nIndustries ii WHERE u.idUserName = :username ]
```

Here the .aj files generated by Roo:

```
privileged aspect Users_Roo_DbManaged {
...    
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IdCompany", referencedColumnName = "IdCompany", nullable = false)
private Company Users.idCompany;  ...
```

..

```
privileged aspect Company_Roo_DbManaged {
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IdCity", referencedColumnName = "IdCity", nullable = false)
private City Company.idCity;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IdIndustry", referencedColumnName = "IdIndustry", nullable = false)
private Industry Company.idIndustry; ..
```

..

```
    privileged aspect Industry_Roo_DbManaged {    ..
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idIndustry")
private Set<I18nIndustry> Industry.i18nIndustries; ...
```

Can you please give me a clue, about what is happening here ?

Spring MVC 3.2,
Roo 1.2.4,
MSSql database

Thanks folks!
--JR

Comment: Confirm , isthis your HQL executing `[select u.idUserName, u.isActiveInd, u.employeeNbr, u.name, c.name as CompanyName, ii.name as IndustryName from Users u JOIN u.idCompany c JOIN c.idIndustry i JOIN FETCH i.i18nIndustries ii WHERE u.idUserName = :username ]`?

Answer (score 1):

About

> These are a couple of question, should Spring Roo through reverse engineering adding FetchType.LAZY for Set fields in .aj files or should I do it manually?

This is not needed because this is the default for this kind of relationship (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765381/2295657).

> If FetchType.LAZY is not present at .aj files, I could make it through the queries " SELECT st1 FROM parentTable t1 JOIN FETCH t1.childTable st1" into the select, right ?

This makes a *eager loading* of the relationship data. I think you are in a mistake about the meaning of LAZY and EAGER modes:

- EAGER: Requires to load value when instance is loaded into memory (default for basic and no-collections-relationship properties)
- LAZY: when instance is loaded a *proxy* is stored in property and, when anything tries to get data, loads it form DB (default for collections-relationship properties)

On the other hand, to load a LAZY property requires a DB Connection alive when anything tries to get the data, so, you must execute this code inside a no-static, `@Transactional` annotated, method (read `@Transactional` JavaDoc for more info).

I advice you to make a look in the JPA specification. In my experience, I so useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found whats happening, This is your HQL

> [select u.idUserName, u.isActiveInd, u.employeeNbr, u.name, c.name as CompanyName, ii.name as IndustryName from Users u JOIN u.idCompany c JOIN c.idIndustry i JOIN FETCH i.i18nIndustries ii WHERE u.idUserName = :username ]

What i understand from this hql is u want to fetch list of `i18nIndustries ii` along with that perticuler `idIndustry i` correct?

But when you use `JOIN FETCH` on any object you have to select the main object to hold child object, in your case main object is `idIndustry`. `JOIN FETCH i.i18nIndustries ii`  means "when fetching `idIndustry`, also fetch the `i18nIndustries`, linked to the `idIndustry`". But your query doesn't fetch `idIndustry` So the fetch makes no sense.

In select either u have to fetch `i` also so that the owner (i) of the fetched association (i.i18nIndustries ii) will present in the select list. as your error is

> query specified join fetching, but the **owner of the fetched
>   association was not present in the select list**

or remove `JOIN FETCH` just use `JOIN`

So keeping in mind u want list of `i18nIndustries ii`, Your query will become :(added `i` in select)

> select u.idUserName, u.isActiveInd, u.employeeNbr, u.name, c.name as
>   CompanyName, **i**,ii.name as IndustryName from Users u JOIN u.idCompany c
>   JOIN c.idIndustry i JOIN FETCH i.i18nIndustries ii WHERE u.idUserName
>   = :username

Comment: Thank you for this detail Amogh, it's clear for me now.

Comment: Sure Amogh!, thank you.! Unfortunately, I'm getting "Vote Up requires 15 reputation".. and I'm not really sure how does it work, I read the tuto and supposedly just a click on arrow up is enough. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up