# Java HibernateCriteria setFetch not Working

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

i have a Criteria like this

```
 final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Computer.class)
 final Criteria studentCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("student","s");
 final Criteria schoolCriteria = studentCriteria.createCriteria("school");
```

everything works OK. but in `SchoolCriteria` i need the `Address` which is a property of the School entity

my question is why this is not working

```
 schoolCriteria.setFetchMode("address",FetchMode.JOIN);
```

i could not see the JOIN in the `SQL statement`

i just thought that if i am already in the schoolCriteria i could just get the address..

but this is working

```
criteria.setFetchMode("student",FetchMode.JOIN);criteria.setFetchMode("student.school",FetchMode.JOIN);criteria.setFetchMode("student.school.address",FetchMode.JOIN);
```

why this.

i am using Hibernate 4.1.5

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot directly fetch child object without fetching parent. when you are trying to do `schoolCriteria.setFetchMode("address",FetchMode.JOIN);` means you want address object (which is a property of the School entity) after even `session` get closed but `school` object is loaded so how can you set `address` object into `student`.

You have to do like JamesB given, Read More @ [Spring Roo doesn't add FetchType.LAZY for fields in .aj files, Should I do it manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479665/spring-roo-doesnt-add-fetchtype-lazy-for-fields-in-aj-files-should-i-do-it-ma/24481615?noredirect=1)

Comment: but i am fetching the parent with `final Criteria schoolCriteria = studentCriteria.createCriteria("school");` right? this bring me the full `SCHOOL object` by inner join.. i just thought if i got the `SCHOOL object` already loaded is just get the `address` object by left outer join right with address?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to chain the joins together like this:

```
session.createCriteria(Computer.class)
       .setFetchMode("student", FetchMode.JOIN)
       .setFetchMode("school", FetchMode.JOIN)
       .setFetchMode("address", FetchMode.JOIN)
```

Comment: but my db is a computer have a student. and student have a school. i need the computer bring the student with a join bring the school with a join and later bring the address by left outer join.

Comment: it works using `school.createAlias("address","a");` but i just thought is easier to write school.setFetchMode("address",FetchMode.JOIN);